# Ubuntu 16.04 headless server is unreachable on LAN without GPU

Tags: networking, server, graphics, ssh

I set up a headless Ubuntu 16.04 server using my old PC. Everything is fine if the graphics card is installed (even without monitor). I can SSH or ping it from LAN. If I remove the graphics card, the server becomes unreachable. SSH will get an operation timeout error. Ping will get a "host is down" error.

I can confirm the BIOS is not preventing Ubuntu from booting by the log:

```
Jan  6 21:45:03 centaurus kernel: [   20.097907] audit: type=1400 audit(1483710302.488:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=746 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  6 21:45:03 centaurus kernel: [   20.106215] audit: type=1400 audit(1483710302.496:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=749 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  6 21:45:03 centaurus kernel: [   20.643765] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignoredi

*I pressed the powerbutton to shutdown (gracefully)
*I installed the graphics card and turned on

Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
```

This is the (partial) boot log with graphics card installed:

```
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   20.278940] audit: type=1400 audit(1483710493.640:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=738 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   20.287161] audit: type=1400 audit(1483710493.648:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=741 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   20.377338] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   20.377340] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   20.377395] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   21.513511] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   22.467902] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link up
Jan  6 21:48:16 centaurus kernel: [   22.467917] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
```

I can see there were some extra lines showing that ethernet was working. So how do I make it reachable without the GPU?